# How can I get a list of all the registered tags and filters in my Django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm trying to debug a problem with a custom tags.

**I'm wondering how I can get a simple `print()` of all the template tags and/or filters that have been registered.**

(The sort of thing to put in at the bottom of `settings.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some commands from `python manage.py shell`

```
from django.contrib.admindocs.views import load_all_installed_template_libraries

load_all_installed_template_libraries()

from django.template import libraries

print(libraries)

# Enjoy!
```